# Can I use DBNull.Value in SQLiteCommand

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

Lets imagine next situation, I am using ADO.NET Data Provider for SQLite, and want to select a user from SQLite db by his name and email (email is NULL).

```
using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
{
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UserId FROM User WHERE Name=@Name and Email=@Email";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", userName);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", ((object)userEmail) ?? DBNull.Value);
   var user = (int?)cmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0;
}
```

As the result I can't get existing user.
The question is: Can I use DBNull.Value with SQLiteCommand?

Comment: can you show some more code for example where are you assigning userName variable and userEmail variable..? also just curious why you feel the need to return Nullable (int?) have you considered using `SQLiteDataAdapter`

Comment: @DJKRAZE: According to Microsoft "If the first column of the first row in the result set is not found, a null reference is returned.". See [DbCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I know what ExecuteScalar does I have never seen anyone return the int that way.. I am just curious

Comment: in case no rows was found ExecuteScalar returns null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would end up with `= NULL` which is not valid as nothing is equal to null.

How about `... WHERE Name=@Name and (Email=@Email or @Email IS NULL)`

Comment: And I think that you can just add the parameter as `null`. No need to convert it to `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: ... WHERE Name=@Name and (Email=@Email or @Email IS NULL) - that means, in case you select "user1" with "email1" it can get "user1" with email equals null